# MySQL Group Replication Vs InnoDB cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-innodb-cluster

I am new to MySQL world. I would like to understand the difference between MySQL Group Replication and InnoDB cluster, is there any other differences apart from router configuration for InnoDB cluster?

can someone please clarify my queries.

Regards,
Var

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think one of them is a component of the other.

Answer (score 0):

[InnoDB Cluster is a combination of MySQL technologies](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-introduction.html) which includes Group Replication, MySQL Shell, and MySQL Router. The fault tolerance is indeed using Group Replication under the hood, and MySQL Shell (and the [Admin API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/admin-api-overview.html) in particular) simplifies configuration and management. [MySQL Router](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/) is used for automatically proxying traffic from clients to the appropriate instance.